# When exactly does JPA perform the commit?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

We are using a clustered Glassfish 2.x with TopLink and an Oracle database. 
JTA is the specified transaction type of the persistence unit, and we use the default caching.

Now we have seen some behaviour I can't quite understand: On GF node 1 an update for an entity is performed, and 5 seconds later, another update for the same entity is performed on node 2. However when looking into the database, it seems like the updates were applied in the wrong order. Is this even possible? From my understanding, it should be that after each WS method end, a commit should be performed against the database. So there should be no way with a 5sec delay, that these two operations got mixed up.

The updates are on the same column and only that column, if that matters. So it should not even matter if the client did see the changes from the first update during the 2nd call, as he just uses the entity's primary key and the new column value to call the WS method. Within the method, the entity is fetched, the new column value is applied and entityManager.merge() is called. So I don't suspect the caching to be an issue here.

Both WS method calls/updates did not throw an exception. I am not able to check the DB logs as it is beyond my control. The behaviour occurs once in a while.
Does anybody have a clue what might be the reason for the behaviour we are experiencing? Is it somewhere documented when the commit really is being performed? Thanks!

Comment: One question: within a transaction you fetch the entity by its primary key first, update the column and after that you call merge on this entity? If yes please check if merge is necessary: it updates an detached entity only and is ignored on managed ones (excepted merge is to be cascaded).

Comment: To tackle the issue further consider the usage of a version column. This may help to detect race conditions.